# Algorithm to null all 'bad' columns and rows

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, space-complexity

Given byte matrix(all values are 1 bit in memory), call it's raw or column 'bad' if it has at least one zero in it. Find algorithm, which takes O(1) additional memory.

I don't know how to do it without having another value, like -1, or another duplicate matrix, to track already found nulls, and not mistaken them with nulls that we filled.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A is the Byte Matrix provided to you. This solution uses constant additional space. Use the first row and column in the matrix to act as flag.
Just one extra flag(here r1) for row1 is required.

```
void setZeroes(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
    int m = A.size();
    int n = A[0].size();
    int r1 = 1; //row1
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        r1 *= A[0][j];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){ //first row skipped
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            A[0][j] *= A[i][j]; //Marking Colm
            A[i][0] *= A[i][j]; //Marking rows, skipping row#1
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++){
            A[i][j] = A[0][j] * A[i][0];
        }
    }
    //At last, update colm1.
    for(int j = 1; j < m; j++){
        A[j][0] *= A[0][0];
    }
    //At last, update row1.
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        A[0][j] *= r1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is using O(1) space. Here are the steps:

1. Find a first row with all 1 values. If there is no such a row so all rows contains at least one 0 so all matrix should became a 0s. Keep the index of row in variable I.
2. Use I-th row as a flag to keep value for each column i.e. `&` whole column and store in I-th row.
3. `&` every row except I-th and set value to the elements of that particular row i.e. take 1st row if it has at least one 0 set whole row to 0s otherwise leave row with all 1s, take second row and so on except I the row.
4. `&` I-th row to all other rows i.e. `A[i][j] &= A[I][j]` for all `i <> I` and `j=0,1,...,A[I].length-1` .

Thats all!!!

As an example we have

`1 1 1 0 1 0`
`1 1 1 1 1 1`
`1 0 1 1 1 1`
`1 1 1 1 1 1`
`0 1 1 1 1 0`

After 1st step we will find I=1 the second row.

Then we are changing 2nd row only, the matrix will became after 2nd step (it changed 1st, 2nd, 4th and last elements to 0 because found 0s in that columns):

`1 1 1 0 1 0`
`0 0 1 0 1 0`
`1 0 1 1 1 1`
`1 1 1 1 1 1`
`0 1 1 1 1 0`

After step 3 matrix will became (we will set 0s to the rows which has at least one 0 excep 2nd row):

`0 0 0 0 0 0`
`0 0 1 0 1 0`
`0 0 0 0 0 0`
`1 1 1 1 1 1`
`0 0 0 0 0 0`

After step 4 matrix will became following (we are doing `&` operations through all columns):

`0 0 0 0 0 0`
`0 0 1 0 1 0`
`0 0 0 0 0 0`
`0 0 1 0 1 0`
`0 0 0 0 0 0`

That is the matrix we are looking for.